# Why is AutoMapper using a bound property as source?

Tags: c#, wpf, automapper

I am building a WPF app and figured I would use AutoMapper to make copies of objects in my viewmodels. The problem I am having is that appears that AutoMapper is attempting to use a bound control as a source value and I don't understand why. I am new to AutoMapper so I figure I am missing some detail.

**Details**

UI has a list box and three buttons (Add, Edit, Delete). If nothing is selected in the list box, then only the Add button is active.

If an item is selected in the list box then all buttons are active.

If the Add button is clicked, a new empty object is created with properties bound to text boxes in the UI.

If the Edit button is clicked, a copy of the item selected in the list box is made and the copy's properties are bound to the text boxes in the UI.

All of this works. The problem occurs if I try to use AutoMapper to make the copy.

Here is the code in question. I have included what works (doing the copy manually, property by property) and the code that fails when using AutoMapper.

There are three properties in the viewmodel involved:

```
    // Bound to the list box's ItemsSource property
    public ObservableCollection<CarType> CarTypes
    {
        get { return _carTypes; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _carTypes, value); }
    }

    // Bound to the list box's SelectedIndex property
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedIndex, value);
        }
    }

    // Properties of CarTypeDto are bound to text boxes in the Edit UI
    public CarType CarTypeDto
    {
        get
        {
            // When the value is retrieved, a copy of the selected item
            // is made and the copy is returned.
            if (SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                // What works==========
                // CarType newDto = new CarType();
                // CarType src = CarTypes[SelectedIndex];
                // newDto.Id = src.Id;
                // newDto.Name = src.Name;
                // newDto.Description = src.Description;
                // _carTypeDto = newDto;

                // What does NOT work============
                CarType src = CarTypes[SelectedIndex];
                CarType newDto = _mapper.Map<CarType>(src); <=== fails here
                _carTypeDto = newDto;

                // Incorrect Solution #1 ======================
                // Changed the above two lines to this solves the problem:
                _mapper.Map<CarType, CarType>(src,_carTypeDto);

            }
            return _carTypeDto;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _carTypeDto, value);
        }
    }
```

When I try to use AutoMapper it gets to the line that fails and the debugger shows this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'CarTypeDto' value (type 'CarType') from '' (type 'CarTypesViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=CarTypeDto.Description; DataItem='CarTypesViewModel' (HashCode=66939890); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='DescriptionTextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

What is confusing me is that I get a reference to the selected item (src) and attempt to map that to a new instance of CarType (newDto). Neither of these items (src or newDto) is part of the binding to the DescriptionTextBox in the editing UI. Why is the binding becoming an issue when I use AutoMaper?

The commented code (manually copying properties) works fine.

In case it helps, here are the bindings in question:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ContentView"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding CarTypes}"
                 Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                 Foreground="{StaticResource ControlForegroundBrush}"
                 BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlForegroundBrush}"
                 SelectedIndex ="{Binding SelectedIndex}" >


<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Name="NameTextBox"
                 Margin="5"
                 Width="100"
                 MaxLength="10"
                 Text="{Binding CarTypeDto.Name, Mode=TwoWay, 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Name="DescriptionTextBox"
                 Margin="5"
                 Width="300"
                 MaxLength="30"
                 Text="{Binding CarTypeDto.Description, 
                 Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In the bootstrap portion of the app I initialize the mapper like so...

```
private void InitializeAutomapper()
    {
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<CarType, CarType>();
        });

        _mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig);
    }
```

...and then inject _mapper into the viewmodels as needed. I have tested the mapper and it will correctly map objects. The issue shows up when I attempt to do the mapping in the CarTypeDto property shown above.

**==============================**
**EDIT - Note about the solution**
I wanted to add a note about the solution for folks who may read this later - especially folks newer to AutoMapper and property binding (like myself).

The answer below made me realize that my approach to populating the CarTypeDto property was not correct. In the final solution I revamped the property to this:

```
public CarType CarTypeDto
{
    get { return _carTypeDto; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _carTypeDto, value); }
}
```

Then, I update the value to the CarTypeDto property elsewhere when needed. For example when the Edit button  is clicked, I then retrieve the selected value and map it to CarTypeDto. The code shown at the top of this post is not the appropriate way to populate the value for a bound property.

While all of this had nothing to do with AutoMapper, when I tried to use AutoMapper it brought the larger problem to light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error mentioned by you is a binding error not the Automapper exception message.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'CarTypeDto' value (type 'CarType') from '' (type 'CarTypesViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=CarTypeDto.Description; DataItem='CarTypesViewModel' (HashCode=66939890); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='DescriptionTextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Now about mapping is not working ---- Before using `Automapper`, the map should be created so that `AutoMapper` can understand how to map one object/type to another. In your scenario, since you need to type from same type then you should create a map like

```
_mapper.CreateMap<MyType, MyType>();
```

The `CreateMap` should be called in `Automapper` **profile initialization**.

Update on your binding error:

The binding error is appearing as you are trying to create a new Object of `CarType` everytime in Get property so `CarTypeDto` property is not pointing to the object which was bound initially at XAML. Instead of creating a new object by mapper you should work on same object and update the property.

Comment: I initialize the mapper elsewhere and inject it into the viewmodel. I have updated the original post to include this detail. Part of my confusion about the error is that it only shows up if I use AutoMapper.

Comment: The binding error is appearing as you are trying to create a new Object  of `CarType` everytime in Get property so `CarTypeDto` property is not pointing to the object which was bound initially at XAML parsing. Instead of creating a new object by mapper you should work on same `object` and update the property (which I believe should be notifying).

Comment: You want to create a new object everytime then property get is not a right place to do. you should rezig your code according to the needs your have.

Comment: That was the issue - thanks! I have updated the original to show the solution.